# Copy rows that do not match criteria from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA copies all rows (excluding the header) from one worksheet to the next empty row on a different worksheet.

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()

Dim copy_from As Range
Dim copy_to As Range

Set copy_from = Worksheets("Shipping Data").UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
Set copy_to = Worksheets("Parts shipped YTD").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

copy_from.Copy Destination:=copy_to
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

I would like to only copy the rows that do not have "Not Shipped" in column R to the second worksheet.  I would then like to delete the rows from the original sheet leaving only the ones that are "Not Shipped".

Comment: You'll need t apply AutoFilter? Would you like a quick example?

Comment: Yes please,  The examples of auto filter all seem to be around filtering on a word rather than excluding it.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hereby and example using `AutoFilter`:

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()

'Get all variables ready first
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Shipping Data")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Parts shipped YTD")
Dim lr1 As Long: lr1 = ws1.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
Dim lr2 As Long: lr2 = ws2.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
Dim lc As Long: lc = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(lr1, lc))

'Apply test before AutoFilter
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng.Columns(18), "<>Not Shipped") > 1 Then

    'Apply filter and copy visible rows
    rng.AutoFilter 18, "<>Not Shipped"
    rng.Offset(1).Resize(lr1 - 1, lc).SpecialCells(12).Copy ws2.Cells(lr2, 1)
    rng.Offset(1).Resize(lr1 - 1, lc).SpecialCells(12).Rows.EntireRow.Delete
    rng.AutoFilter

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this.   It sort of works, but overwrites the last row on the sheet it is pasting to instead of going to the next empty row.  The Delete function also throws a Run-time error '1004': Delete method of Range class failed.